# Using Qt Creator for non-qt Android c++ development

Tags: android, c++, linux, qt

I'm trying to setup Qt Creator for Android C++ development that uses non-Qt libraries. Testing with a simple Hello World, I have a problem in deploying the compiled program to AVD through Qt Creator. The deployment process always stuck with an error message of;

> Install to device: emulator-5554 No platform plugin, neither
>   libqtforandroid.so or libqtforandroidGL.so, included in package.
>   Please include one. 06:34:06: The process
>   "/home/dev/Qt5.3.0/5.3/android_armv7/bin/androiddeployqt" exited with
>   code 12. Error while building/deploying project helloworld (kit:
>   Android for armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.8, Qt 5.3.0)) When executing step
>   'Deploy to Android device'

How should I go about it?

Thanks.

Comment: I recently watched a video on YouTube and an experienced developer said that in fact you can't use pure C++, it's going to be a java-translated source code/api anyway. That's just about non-qt libraries. But I can be wrong here.